# I'm working with lti1.3 to build a lti tool which can be then integrated to many LMS platforms

Tags: java, spring-boot, moodle, lti

I have the client details that is get created on moodle. Also I did hit the https://localhost/mod/lti/token.php api and get the bearer token.

I wanted to get the user details but not able to figure out where I can find them. I'm confused if it has something to do with the scope as I didn't provide anything in the scope and send the request. I did commented the scope section in token.php file to get the output as I'm not sure what exactly I have to send in the scope.

This is the api I hit from the postman after creating the JWToken manually.
[token.php api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8h7On.png)

Also, what is the use of https://localhost/mod/lti/auth.php api. Please tell me about these things.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reading the section of the IMS security framework that explains the [OpenID Connect Launch flow](https://www.imsglobal.org/spec/security/v1p1#openid_connect_launch_flow). This will help you understand the purpose of the mod/lti/auth.php endpoint.

With regards to user details, you'd normally get these one of two main ways in LTI 1.3:

1. Via the JWT the tool receives as part of a Resource Link Launch. See the section of the LTI 1.3 core spec describing [user identity claims](https://www.imsglobal.org/spec/lti/v1p3#user-identity-claims).
2. Via a service call to the [Names and Role Provisioning Service](https://www.imsglobal.org/spec/lti-nrps/v2p0)

If you're making a service call to the NRPS service, you need to make sure you request a token with the relevant scope: 'https://purl.imsglobal.org/spec/lti-nrps/scope/contextmembership.readonly'. See the [Scope and service security section](https://www.imsglobal.org/spec/lti-nrps/v2p0#lti-1-3-integration) of the specification.